# Adobe SDK image editor not working in IE11

Tags: adobecreativesdk

We are trying to implement Adobe Creative SDK to edit image. It is working fine with Google chrome but not working in Internet Explorer 11. While opening the image in editor , it is making one more call to

https://featherservices.aviary.com/imgjsonpserver.aspx which is giving

> 503 service unavailable error

. This url is not getting called in case of Chrome which is why it is working fine in Chrome.

Please post your suggestion if anyone had faced this issue earlier.

Answer (score 0):

they already stop the development of this. Kindly read http://blog.aviary.com/archive/eol/